# Best (api4) way to chain save a contact so that the email updates, without creating a new one?

Tags: chaining, apiv4

Using civicrm api4, what's the best way to chain save a contact so that the email updates, without creating a new one?

For example, I want to update this existing contact:

```
entity: Contact, action: get, version: 4, count: 1
(1) [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Michael",
    "email.email": "cio@agloa.org"
  }
]
```

... to have first_name: "Mike" and email: "mike@agloa.org". So, I tried:

```
crmApi4('Contact', 'save', {
  records: [{"id":2, "first_name":"Mike"}],
  chain: {"name_me_0":["Email", "save", {"records":[{"contact_id":"$id", "email":"mike@agloa.org"}]}]}
})
```

That correctly updates the first name, but *creates* a new email:

```
entity: Contact, action: get, version: 4, count: 2
(2) [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Mike",
    "email.id": 2,
    "email.email": "cio@agloa.org"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Mike",
    "email.id": 11,
    "email.email": "mike@agloa.org"
  }
]
```

How can I get it to simply update the existing email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got what I needed by including the email id (**"id":2**) in the records chain property:

```
crmApi4('Contact', 'save', {
  records: [{"id":2, "first_name":"Mike"}],
  chain: {"name_me_0":["Email", "save", {"records":[{"contact_id":"$id", "email":"mike@agloa.org", "id":2}]}]}
})
```